# Using MySQL join to show unrelated records

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I have a table of machines, and a table representing the reachability if these machines across time.

```
machines
id    name
1     machine1
2     machine2
3     machine3
4     machine4

machines_reachability
machine_id    is_reachable    time
1             0               (whatever)
2             1               (whatever)
3             0               (whatever)
1             1               (whatever)
2             0               (whatever)
3             0               (whatever)
1             1               (whatever)
2             1               (whatever)
3             1               (whatever)
```

I'm trying to find machines that has **NO** reachability records (i.e. machine4) **using JOINS**. This can be done in another ways but I need to do this through joins to have a better understanding of it.

I tried the following

```
SELECT * FROM machines m LEFT OUTER JOIN machines_reachability mr ON m.id = mr.machine_id
```

I understand that this should output the whole left table contents (i.e. machines) and the `OUTER` keyword should **exclude** the intersection of results between `machines` and `machines_reachability` tables based on the condition `m.id = mr.machine_id`. But that didn't work as I expected. It showed all contents but **didn't exclude** the rows that **didn't** match.

So how can I run a `JOIN` query that actually shows the rows that **didn't** join whether it's the left table or the right one selectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select distinct machines.names where machines natural left outer join machines_rechability where is_reachable is null

Comment: If I ommit `where is_reachable is null`, I can't find rows with the value of `is_reachable` to be `null`. So how does this condition work in the first place ?!

Comment: If you remove is_reachable is null condition then you will receive a table with 
Machine1
Machine2
Machine3
Machine4

Answer (score 1):

Using joins:

```
select *
from machines m left outer join
     machines_reachability mr
     on m.id = mr.machine_id and
        mr.is_reachable = 1
where mr.machine_id is NULL
```

The idea is to start with all the machines.  The `left join` keeps all records in the first table, even those that do not match.  There is a match in the second table when a machine is reachable (I assume the record has to have the flag set as well as being in the table).  The final `where` clause keeps only machines that have no match in the second table.

Comment: One thing confusing me, If I do not filter by `mr.machine_id IS NULL`, I get all rows from the `machines` table but not no rows from the `machines_reachability` table with `machine_id` equal to `NULL`. So why does `WHERE mr.machine_id IS NULL` work in the first place ?!

Comment: Ah now I get it. Thank you.

Comment: You and `John smith` answered a correct answer but he is a few minutes earlier and I had to accept his answer to be fair enough. Thanks a lot for your time though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM machines m
JOIN machines_reachability mr
  ON (m.id <> mr.machine_id)
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Comment: I'm trying to find `machines` that has no information in the `machines_reachability` table.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
SELECT * from machines where not exists 
( 
      select machine_id from machines_reachability 
      where machines.id = machines_reachability.machine_id 
);
```

Comment: I need to do it using `JOIN`

Comment: I'm actually studying `JOINS`, not trying to produce results.